# Matlab - batch jobs won't leave queued status

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I've got some code that, as it iterates through a loop, grows by some percent in what is to be processed each time. The first few iterations take 4 seconds, but by the 100th, they're taking minutes - and this is for a lite selection of parameters, as I intend to do 350 iterations. To do serious research with this would take enormous time, and it's really inconvenient that simply running a script ties Matlab's hands behind its back until it's all done, and on top of that it hardly ever uses more than one core at a time.

I understand that turning on a Parallel Pool will enable parallel processing. Even if I can't convert any of the `for` loops into `parfor` loops, I understand that running a script as a `batch` job sends that process into the background, and I can do other things with the Matlab interface and the other 7 processors while I wait for this one to finish.

However, though I have the local parallel pool up and running, and I've checked the syntax for starting a batch job, it's not leaving the "queued" status. The first time I typed in `batch('Script4')` and hit Enter, and then realized I must have a variable name for the job, so then I did `run1 = batch('Script4')`. I typed `get(run1,'State')`, and also checked the Job Monitor, and both told me that its state was "queued".

I did some googling before I came here, and while I found some Q&As of similar experiences, they seemed to be solved by things like waiting for the pool to stop using the whole CPU as it starts up. But I started my pool up a long time ago (and it is still running at this moment!), and when I entered the first `batch` command, my first clue that something was wrong was that Windows Task Manager said all 8 cores were at 0%.

Is there something I need to call or maybe adjust before it will start executing the queued jobs?

I'm using Matlab R2015a on Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: I tried running a function that called `parfor` in the command window, and it did in .141 sec what it took .235 sec to do when I removed the "par", so it looks like the toolbox is working.

Comment: You should share your code, it is complicated to analyse without any additional information. A candid guess though, do you have dynamic reallocation of matrices in your code?

Comment: I understand why changing the structure of a matrix would mess up a parfor loop, but does that really also mess up batch? My understanding of batch is that it puts the script running in the background with as many cores as it would otherwise have had (or maybe more), but it deals with all the variables just as if it was taking the command window, except it doesn't, so it's probably not good for interactive programs. Is there more to it than that?

Comment: If it's a problem of matrix allocation, there is nothing to do with the cpu and changing your code for multi-threading and gpu won't improve much your timing. Consider preallocating your matrices before to go in your loop (it is the reason why your code slow down I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're trying to run `batch` jobs while the parallel pool is open. (Unfortunately, this is a common misunderstanding). Basically, the parallel pool and your `batch` job are both trying to consume local workers. However, because you opened the parallel pool first, it's consuming all the local workers, and the `batch` job cannot proceed. You should have seen a warning when you submit the `batch` job, like this:

```
>> parpool('local');
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... connected to 4 workers.
>> j = batch(@rand, 1, {});
Warning: This job will remain queued until the Parallel Pool is closed.
```

There are two possible fixes - the first is simple

```
delete(gcp('nocreate'))
```

will ensure no parallel pool is open, and your `batch` submissions should proceed. The second is more appropriate if your tasks are relatively short-lived - you can use `parfeval` to submit work to an open parallel pool:

```
f = parfeval(@rand, 1); % initiate 'rand' on the parallel pool workers
fetchOutputs(f); % wait for completion, and retrieve the result
```

Comment: I tried running `j5 = batch(Script4)` and got no error. Now I'll see what the results are like!
(These scripts take on the order of 24 hours to run; I've sped them up severalfold, but in batch I can't see any of the `display` function outputs.)